# How to call value stored in last row and add into a new column? BigQuery - SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Pls, can you help me with this?

I've these columns in my table:

```
date(yyyy/mm/dd) | productcode_str | productname_str |  daysales_int
```

and need to write a query that must output:

```
productcode_X_str | productname_X_str | isoweek_date | isoweek_of_year | weeksales_int | week_sales_last_week | week_difference_to_last_week |
```

I've been trying this so far:

```
SELECT  productcode_str ,
        productname_str , 
        DATE_TRUNC(date, ISOWEEK) AS isoweek_date, 
        EXTRACT(ISOWEEK FROM date) AS isoweek_of_year,
        SUM(daysales_int) AS weeksales_int,
        LAG(SUM(daysales_int)) 
           OVER (PARTITION BY (DATE_TRUNC(date, ISOWEEK)) ORDER BY date) 
           AS week_sales_last_week
FROM my_table
WHERE productcode_str = 'X'
GROUP BY 1, 2, 3, 4 
ORDER BY 3
```

that returns perfectly:

```
productcode_X_str | productname_X_str | isoweek_date | isoweek_of_year | weeksales_int
```

But in LAG query I got this error: "Partition by expression references column date which is neither group nor aggregated"

So, is missing `week_sales_last_week | week_difference_to_last_week`

Does somebody knows how to query these two missing?

Answer (score 0):

Done!

I did it by just:
I) Pulling out "PARTITION BY" clause
II) Insert some aggregation in date

So, the final query is:

```
SELECT  productcode_str ,
        productname_str , 
        DATE_TRUNC(date, ISOWEEK) AS isoweek_date, 
        EXTRACT(ISOWEEK FROM date) AS isoweek_of_year,
        SUM(daysales_int) AS weeksales_int,
        LAG(SUM(daysales_int)) 
           OVER (ORDER BY MAX(date)) 
           AS week_sales_last_week
        (SUM(daysales_int) - LAG(SUM(daysales_int))
           OVER (ORDER BY MAX(date))) AS week_difference_to_last_week
FROM my_table
WHERE productcode_str = 'X'
GROUP BY 1, 2, 3, 4 
ORDER BY 3
```